# Fancybox / Galleriffic conflict - main image navigation link

Tags: javascript, fancybox, gallery, lightbox, galleriffic

I'm in the process of building a web showcase page that uses Fancybox v2.0.6 to open a hidden div when a user clicks a project thumbnail image. Each Fancybox div contains an overview for each project and a Galleriffic gallery of screenshots. I've been able to utilise multiple Galleriffic galleries on this one page thanks to [this Google Group Discussion](http://code.google.com/p/galleriffic/issues/detail?id=76), but have run into issues with the main image.

By default in Galleriffic, users can navigate the gallery by clicking the main enlarged image or by choosing a thumbnail. The thumbnails are working no problems. However, when I click the main image, instead of showing the next image in the gallery, the Fancybox div disappears and a loading spinner appears - I think it belongs to Fancybox. If I then click the spinner div it closes and I'm back to the original webpage.

The best solution would be to remove the linking from the main image and just use the thumbnails to view the gallery. My various attempts have been unsuccessful - either the image vanishes or the spinner just continues to load.

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome at this stage! If you need to see any code to play around with, just let me know and I will post.

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's a [link to a stripped-down version](http://learnline-dev.cdu.edu.au/erin/showcase/showcase.html) - if I view it locally then the loading spinners just sits there, online I get a URL error in the Fancybox: "[object HTMLDivElement] was not found on this server".

Comment: what about sharing a link to see the issue? it would be easier to see the code and suggest a fix than just guessing.

Comment: Sorry @JFK - duh, that would have been sensible! Have added link in update above.